# Combine and separate queries data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm using `CONCAT` to combine multiple columns,

```
SELECT CONCAT(col1, ' - ', col2) AS result
FROM table 
WHERE col1 LIKE '%apple%' OR
      col2 LIKE '%apple%' 
ORDER BY col1 ASC
```

And then return it as json data.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data[] = $row['result'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Question: 
How can I separate the data into its individual field when I read it in jQuery? 
Is it better (more efficient) to send it separately?

```
<script>
   $(function() {
    $( "#AllWord" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'search_apple.php'
    });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: why would you concat the 2 columns if you want the seperate values?

Comment: it's for autocomplete form. showing the two fields instantly. then separate it for other purposes. I can do the other way round too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best will be to send it individually, so the query without the concat.

Encoding:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data[] = $query; // No need to create another array, it is already correct
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

You can still concat (best place will be in the query itself), next to col1 and col2 individually if you need to concat.

And last remark:
Please don't make use of the mysql_* functions.
Please use mysqli_* or PDO.
More information here: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: How can I separate it in my autocomplete function?

Comment: If I send it separately, how can I get the two fields in the  autocomplete function?